# I don't understand how I Wsh work

Tags: grammar, expressions

I learned about i wish i had  vII -> something i regret that i didn't do something in the past and i have now effects of that
And about i wish i had wihout vII -> I regreat that i have to do something now.

But i have some exercise about I wish + Past simple or I wish + would.
[image: my exercise]

and i don't have any idea what they mean and what difference they have.
Somebody could explain me, how this 4 forms differ ?

Answer (score 1):

Wishes (or regrets) about the past use Past Perfect:

> I wish I had asked her out.

That's the easy part. For the other tenses, the general rule is to use Simple Past for wishes about the present:

> I wish you were here.

and "would" for wishes about the future:

> I wish you would come tomorrow.

However, the line between the two latter cases can be a bit blurry without an explicit time indicator, as most wishes for something in the future can also be applicable to the present without much of a change in meaning:

> I wish it **would stop** raining (sometime soon) / I wish it **stopped** raining (now)

Additionally, when our "wish" is a request towards another person, using "would" makes it more polite:

> I wish you **stopped** correcting me. (more firm) / I wish you **would stop** correcting me (more polite)